# Check folder and files permission via T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I want to check all the files and folders permissions in T-SQL.

For example:

- Folder name: `Root`
- Items inside the root are `File1, file2, folder1`

I want the list of users who has permission for these files and folders in T-SQL.

Comment: SQL Server is a **database server** - not a file system frontend...... this is totally the wrong place to do something like this

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question; yes it can; however that'll require you to open up permissions that are so awful I'll not tell you how.

If you absolutely must do this then creating an External Access assembly using .Net and calling that is your answer. If you traverse this road then do NOT go the 'Trustworthy' route and bypass security. Create a asymmetric key and a user and sign your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Although **NOT recommended**, but you can use `xp_cmdshell` to query underlying OS/file-system from within SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

If you need to check if a folder/UCN-path is accessible from within SSMS, place a small database-backup file (.bak) there then use FILELISTONLY restore to simply read it, e.g.:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '\\folder_to_check\db.bak'   --this will only read the file (without performing the Restore operation.
```

If above succeeds in reading the .bak file from your `<folder_to_check>` folder - it means the folder in question is accessible (via T-SQL / from within SSMS).

If not, grant access (such as READ/WRITE access on that folder) to the service account that executes your SQL-instance, which normally is a local system account or an AD-Service account.

To obtain this Service account's name, view ***Properties*** of SQL Server service in "Windows Services" (`services.msc`) or "SQL Server Configuration Manager" (`SQLServerManager<your_SQLServer_Version_number>.msc`) alternatively you can run following query:

```
select * from sys.dm_server_services  --This will list the Accounts-Names that execute SQL Server Instance/engine service & SQL Agent service, and Full-Text Search services etc.
```

HTH.